# unsigned volatile long Vs volatile unsigned long

Tags: c, gcc

I came across a code today where a particular hardware address was type casted to

```
unsigned volatile long *
```

I know it can be `volatile unsigned long` or `unsigned long volatile`; is this another way of defining `volatile` or it is a bug in the code ?

I enabled warnings and surprised to see no warning.  I was using GCC-4.7.0

Answer (score 2):

It's just another way, there's no semantic difference.

Answer (score 0):

The C language allows *type specifiers* (`int, unsigned, char, signed, void` etc), *type qualifiers* (`volatile, const` etc) and *storage class specifiers* (`static, extern` etc) to be combined with each other, written in any order. They are all so-called "declaration specifiers" and the order does not matter.

*However*, in future directions for the C standard (C11 6.11) it is stated that in the future: `"The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature."`

So you should always write storage-class specifiers at the beginning of a declaration. Code that doesn't do such, is not guaranteed to compile in future versions of the C standard.

I would say that because of this, it is good programming style to always write the specifiers in the order `[storage-class specifiers] [type qualifiers] [type specifiers]`, and never to mix the 3 types.

The most proper way to write your declaration is then:

```
volatile unsigned long *
```

Or if you want to be needlessly verbose:

```
auto volatile unsigned long *
```

Comment: That's kind of funny, because it means that the standard now encourages an irregularity in the pattern of `int volatile **x`, `int * volatile *x`, and `int ** volatile x`.

Comment: @sh1 That's not really related, those are "pointer declarators". Your 3 examples have different meanings. Generally, this whole part of the C standard is no easy reading...

Comment: Wait -- no it doesn't.  They're only saying `static` or `auto` should go first, not that `volatile` should.

Comment: the original example was a pointer.  I believe that `unsigned volatile long *` is itself not a volatile object, and so your suggested `volatile unsigned long *` is a little misleading if one were to mistake `volatile` for a storage class specifier.

Comment: Revisiting this with a little more time; the C11 quote refers to *storage-class specifiers*, but that's not what `volatile` is, and so that has no bearing on where in the sequence `volatile` should be placed.  There's no difference between my first example and the original case, which is precisely my point.  Had the standard mandated your order then we'd have a list of `volatile int **x`, `int * volatile *x`, and `int ** volatile x` to represent the three different things which could be volatile.